# Converting timestamp to Calendar in Java

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, timestamp

I want to get the year, month, date and hour from a `long` timestamp value. I found many examples of creating a `Calendar` from a timestamp value, but I don't get what I want.

I wrote  the following

```
long timestamp = 1488866400;

Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis( timestamp );

System.out.println( cal.get( Calendar.YEAR ) );
System.out.println( cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ) );
System.out.println( cal.get( Calendar.DATE ) );
```

`1488866400` is Tue, 07 Mar 2017 06:00:00 GMT, so I expected the code above to give me year `2017`, month `2` and date `7`, but it gives me year `1970`, month `0` and day `17`.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong or if it could be made in a different way?

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date` classes.  You should instead look at the `java.time` package for the class most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. Most any basic date-time question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply your timestamp by 1000.
`long timestamp = 1488866400 * 1000;`

your timestamp is in seconds and calendar uses milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long timestamp = 1488866400;
LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(date.getYear() );
System.out.println( date.getMonth() );
System.out.println( date.getDayOfMonth() );
```